# Broke nested dynamic JSON array with JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm looking for flattening nested JSON file into SQL ready format.

JSON file's content:

```json
{
  "ProductLine": [
    "Product 1",
    "Product 2"
  ],
  "Purchase": 364,
  "Cancel": [
    140,
    2
  ]
}
```

My current transformation:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "ProductLine": "Product 1",
    "Purchase": 364,
    "Cancel": 140
  },
  {
    "ProductLine": "Product 2",
    "Cancel": 2
  }
]
```

The difficulty is that arrays can change, sometimes "Cancel" can be an array or sometimes "Purchase" block can be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

**If `Purchase` or `cancel` be an array or not, this works**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ProductLine": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "[&2].&3",
            "@(3,Purchase[&1])": "[&2].Purchase",
            "@(3,Cancel[&1])": "[&2].Cancel"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

First, change all values to the array. Now you can loop on the `ProductLine` and get other fields from `Purchase` and `Cancel`.

**Update:** The following answer has been obtained in collaboration with [Barbaros Özhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841306/barbaros-%C3%96zhan). Special thanks.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm able to examine yours. Using `cardinality` for this case is such a pretty good idea, great!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you. I learned all this from you.

Answer (score 1):

We can pick `Purchase` at a different(*outer*) level such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2" 
        }
      },
      "Purchase": "[#].&"// at two level less than the inner object
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** one the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : Considering array indeterminance for the attributes, you can use the following spec alternatively

```json
[
  { //reform two separate objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "orj",
      "*": "non_array.&.@0[]"
    }
  },
  { // in order to keep the non-array values as the first component of the newly formed array(s) 
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { //the topmost level 
        "*": { //level for the keys
          "*": "&1[]" //match keys and values to convert non-arrays to arrays
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// pick the first component for the non-array(s)
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=firstElement"
      }
    }
  },
  { // apply the original spec after having got individual array values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the attributes with null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

or another straightforward alternative would be using your original spec after applying cardinality spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when `Cancel` is not an array.

Comment: Its rights according to the exact OP. But at the end of the question it is mentioned that `cancel` can be an array. In this case I think that `cardinality` is force to use for first spec.

Comment: Hi @MohammadReza , I was busier yesterday, can you check this new update out as well please.

Comment: Using `[#2]` in the last solution is a better solution.

Comment: For the `Considering array indeterminance` solution I think it's another solution if we had not the `cardinality` operation in the jolt. It is an interesting solution.

Comment: I respectfully added your last solution to my answer. +1